# ngFor filter retuns no items message in child component

Tags: angular, filter, parent-child, ngfor, children

I have a parent collection that has a collection of children components.

```
[parent]
 [child]
 [child]
[parent]
 [child]
```

I have a filter on the ngFor for the children,

When I filter, it filters the data but my view ends up looking like this:

```
[parent]
[parent]
 [child]
```

Is there anyway to filter out the parent if the child has no items? Or, have it do something like this:

```
[parent]
 No Items Found!
[parent]
 [child]
```

Thanks for any assistance, just learning Angular 7.

html:

```
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div *ngFor="let organization of column.boardColumnWorkItems">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 organization-row">
        {{organization.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-board-column-tile *ngFor="let workItem of organization.workItems | workItemFilter:filterTerm"
                           [boardColumnWorkItem]="workItem">
    </app-board-column-tile>
  </div>
</div>
```

filter/pipe:

```
transform(workItems: any, filterTerm: any): any {
console.log("WorkItemFilterPipe: " + filterTerm);
//Check if filter term is undefined
if (filterTerm === undefined)
  return workItems;
//Return the filtered list of workitems
this.filteredWorkItems = workItems.filter(function (workItem) {
  return workItem.filterData.includes(filterTerm.toLowerCase());
})

console.log(this.filteredWorkItems.length);

return this.filteredWorkItems;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="organization.workItems | workItemFilter:filterTerm as filteredWorkItems">
  <app-board-column-tile *ngFor="let workItem of filteredWorkItems"
                           [boardColumnWorkItem]="workItem">
  </app-board-column-tile>
  <h3 *ngIf="filteredWorkItems.length === 0">No filtered results!</h3>
</ng-container>
```